# Proof regarding a fixed point and a Contraction

Tags: proof-writing, numerical-methods, contraction-operator

So I am having trouble with this proof, the problem statement is as follows. Suppose $g:[a,b] \rightarrow[a,b]$ is a contraction, and let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that for all $x,y \in [a,b]$: $$|g(x)-g(y)| \leq \alpha|x-y|$$Let $x_{n+1}=g(x_{n})$. Prove that if $x^*$ is the fixed point of g, then $|x_n - x^*| < \frac{\alpha^n}{1-\alpha}|x_0-x_1|$. Then it asks to estimate how many iterations it would take.

I think I can handle the second part of the question if I can figure out what $\alpha$ is, but I am just really struggling with the first part of the question. From previous questions that I have done I think that I can use a Taylor series approximation on $g(x)$ to get the left side to the absolute value. If $g'(x^*)\neq 0$ then this approximation would be $$|x_{n+1}-x^*| = |g'(x^*)||x_n-x^*|$$ then I was thinking that the triangle inequality would be useful somewhere else in the proof, but I seem to be having issues, which exactly how useful it would be.

Comment: It sounds like the question treats $\alpha$ as a given (i.e., there is some $\alpha$ associated with the function $g$ such that the contraction property $|g(x)-g(y)| \le \alpha |x-y|$ holds).  You are probably supposed to express the number of iterations as a function of $\alpha$.

Comment: This is asking you to prove the Banach fixed point theorem. The usual approach is to show that for $m > n$, $$|x_m - x_n| < \frac{a^n}{1 - a}|x_1 - x_0|.$$ This shows that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and thus converges to some $x^*$. Then you can take the limit as $m \to \infty$ to get $$|x^* - x_n| \leq \frac{a^n}{1 - a}|x_1 - x_0|$$